# changing 2d list values using loop works uncorrectly

Tags: python, numpy

```
brief = B[:8, :8]

average = 0
for i in range(8):
    average += sum(brief[i])
average -= brief[0][0]
average /= 64

print(average, 'is average\n\n')


for i in range(0, 8):
    for j in range(0, 8):
        if brief[i][j] >= average:
            brief[i][j] = 0
            print(brief[i][j])
        if brief[i][j] < average:
            brief[i][j] = 1
            print(brief[i][j])

for b in range(8):
    for bb in range(8):
        print(brief[b][bb])
```

**brief** is a 8x8 part of B matrix with these values:

```
[[-79.59774442081138,    158.7202095869316,    112.56820969421881,    -59.04458113044859,    110.79507835753822,    65.46782110183209,    -1.3342162705874172,    25.437988304756363],
[322.5377343539482,     8659.5625,             456.1372383004441,     1039.2670348171582,    502.43880254201326,    201.0009891626345,    209.16093093311468,     -208.50047755598916],
[-112.56820969421881,   224.46427302053877,   -159.19548884162273,   -83.50164741931893,    156.6879024574203,     92.58548050122643,    -1.8868667450035765,    35.974748060074624],
[37.72684830839333,     624.7408144869114,    53.3538205433223,      -449.0466120624775,    32.59027278985499,     -43.22267150470408,   -85.65936443956468,     219.2142421380014],
[-28.001674523528344,   249.9757286483847,    -39.60034788033096,    31.11673361617372,     130.48068801733655,    -160.1201473099224,   -112.78964698763158,    -158.7758135283589],
[54.7357856623738,      -359.607876182155,    77.40809043087583,     46.68603856944288,     -89.88043774029418,    282.9769031346061,    27.867634849967388,     -202.2926232693297],
[15.271034089670682,    70.44041778968491,    21.596503521074148,    7.9278092841192915,    -37.515872842738105,   27.38507374399468,    -10.177891707673886,    -118.39173788971809],
[20.304659220046318,    -234.8242040396121,   28.71512444835341,     146.63941111295003,    -59.20821857294881,    -73.98127851564756,   121.3747483435147,      17.835871018082692]]
```

Then I find average, and change every element of **brief** to 0 if it's greater (or equal) than average, and to 1 if it's less than average. In the loop where I compare **brief** elements to average I also print the new values. So the output is `1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 etc...`. As you can see there are 0s and 1s. BUT! When I print **brief** after that loop I get all elements as **1**s. What's wrong with the output?

P.S. B was created as **np.zeros** then filled with numbers

Comment: You are missing a comma in the first row of your sample `brief`. Please edit

Comment: @Bazingaa sorry, missed a comma

Comment: What kind of object is B?

Comment: @Moberg np.zeros

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your double `if` statements with the following lines:

```
for i in range(0, 8):
    for j in range(0, 8):
        if brief[i][j] >= average:
            brief[i][j] = 0
        else:
            brief[i][j] = 1
```

The problem was that in your code you first assign `brief[i][j] = 0` and then you again check in the second `if` statement `if brief[i][j] < average:` which means `if 0 < average`, which is always true for your value of `average` and hence everything becomes `1`